# Solr language detection not work with pdf

Tags: solr, lucene, language-detection

I have configured **Solr 7.7.3** to detect **English** and **Japanese** documents.
It can work normally with text based files like docx, xlsx ... but when I convert to pdf Solr can't detect or sometimes output wrong language(I used Microsoft Office 2019 to convert docx to pdf).

I also tried methods: **Tika**, **LangDetect** and **OpenNLP** from this page https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/detecting-languages-during-indexing.html

**Please help me. Thank you so much!!!**

**solrconfig.xml**

```
   <updateRequestProcessorChain name="langid">
     <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
       <str name="langid.fl">_text_</str>
       <str name="langid.langField">language</str>
       <str name="langid.langsField">languages</str>
       <str name="langid.fallback">fr</str>
       <str name="langid.threshold">0.7</str>
       <str name="langid.model">langdetect-183.bin</str>
       <str name="langid.whitelist">en-US,en-GB,en,ja</str>
     </processor>
     <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
     <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

```
    <requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                    startup="lazy"
                    class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
      <str name="update.chain">langid</str>
    </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

**managed-schema**

```
  <field name="language" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="languages" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**Log when I tried with file Test.docx**

> 2021-01-27 07:25:57.177 DEBUG (qtp1571967156-58) [   x:doc_analyzer]
> o.a.s.u.p.LanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessor ***Language fallback to
> value fr*** 2021-01-27 07:25:57.178 DEBUG (qtp1571967156-58) [
> x:doc_analyzer] o.a.s.u.p.LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessor
> Appending field *text* 2021-01-27 07:25:57.184 DEBUG
> (qtp1571967156-58) [   x:doc_analyzer]
> o.a.s.u.p.LanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessor ***Language detected ja
> with certainty 0.9999999780558492*** 2021-01-27 07:25:57.185 DEBUG
> (qtp1571967156-58) [   x:doc_analyzer]
> o.a.s.u.p.LanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessor Detected main document
> language from fields [*text*]: ja 2021-01-27 07:25:57.185 DEBUG
> (qtp1571967156-58) [   x:doc_analyzer]
> o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory PRE_UPDATE
> add{,id=Test.docx,commitWithin=1000}
> {langid.whitelist=en-US,en-GB,en,ja&update.chain=langid&df=*text*&commitWithin=1000&langid.langField=language&literal.id=Test.docx&fmap.meta=ignored_&lowernames=true&langid.model=langdetect-183.bin&langid.fallback=fr&langid.threshold=0.7&fmap.content=*text*&langid.langsField=languages&langid.fl=*text*&overwrite=true&wt=json}

**Log when I tried with file Test.pdf**

> 2021-01-27 07:30:56.643 DEBUG (qtp1571967156-19) [   x:doc_analyzer] o.a.s.u.p.LanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessor ***Language fallback to value fr***
> 2021-01-27 07:30:56.643 DEBUG (qtp1571967156-19) [   x:doc_analyzer] o.a.s.u.p.LanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessor ***Language detected en-US with certainty 1.0***
> 2021-01-27 07:30:56.643 DEBUG (qtp1571967156-19) [   x:doc_analyzer] o.a.s.u.p.LanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessor Field language already contained value en-US, not overwriting.
> 2021-01-27 07:30:56.644 DEBUG (qtp1571967156-19) [   x:doc_analyzer] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory PRE_UPDATE add{,id=Test.pdf,commitWithin=1000} {langid.whitelist=en-US,en-GB,en,ja&update.chain=langid&df=*text*&commitWithin=1000&langid.langField=language&literal.id=Test.pdf&fmap.meta=ignored_&lowernames=true&langid.model=langdetect-183.bin&langid.fallback=fr&langid.threshold=0.7&fmap.content=*text*&langid.langsField=languages&langid.fl=*text*&overwrite=true&wt=json}

**@Files**: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1igD_XCEGsIm08shLShXJ7IMV4qFscdGh?usp=sharing